# Hive CTE, can I query values as table?

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive, common-table-expression

I'm trying to create in-query dimension table that I want to later use in my data pull. In MS SQL I can get away with this CTE which will use values as table:

```
with tbl_test_values as (select * from (
    VALUES  
        ('Number','1','One'),
        ('Number','5','Five'),
        ('Letter','A','First Letter'),
        ('Human','Bob','Dude')
    ) as 
    TestValues --equivalent of table name
    (Name, Value, Descript) --essentially field names
)
select * from actual_data_table f 
left outer join tbl_test_values d on f.Name=d.Name
```

Is there a way to replicate the above CTE "tbl_test_values" in Hive, i.e. query custom set of values as table?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean without having to create any table.. make it a clear question

Comment: I mean that tbl_test_values will not exist outside query. In my case "actual_data_table" is physical that resides in DB and "tbl_test_values" exists only inside the script

Comment: then create  a table in your Database.. if you dont need temp table

Comment: the goal is to get around creating the table

Comment: what do you mean get around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1.

**inline**

```
with    tbl_test_values as
        (
            select  inline
                    (
                        array
                        (
                            struct ('Number','1','One')
                           ,struct ('Number','5','Five')
                           ,struct ('Letter','A','First Letter')
                           ,struct ('Human','Bob','Dude')
                        )
                    ) as (Name, Value, Descript)
        )

select * from tbl_test_values
;
```

---

```
+--------+-------+--------------+
|  name  | value |   descript   |
+--------+-------+--------------+
| Number | 1     | One          |
| Number | 5     | Five         |
| Letter | A     | First Letter |
| Human  | Bob   | Dude         |
+--------+-------+--------------+
```

#### 2.

**stack**

```
with    tbl_test_values as
        (
            select  stack
                    (
                        4
                       ,'Number' ,'1'   ,'One'
                       ,'Number' ,'5'   ,'Five'
                       ,'Letter' ,'A'   ,'First Letter'
                       ,'Human'  ,'Bob' ,'Dude'
                    ) as (Name, Value, Descript)
        )

select * from tbl_test_values
;
```

---

```
+--------+-------+--------------+
|  name  | value |   descript   |
+--------+-------+--------------+
| Number | 1     | One          |
| Number | 5     | Five         |
| Letter | A     | First Letter |
| Human  | Bob   | Dude         |
+--------+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Dudu, this is exactly what I was looking for.